# Bash: List file size using ls , awk and grep

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, ls

I entered the following commands on the terminal:

```
ls -l someFile | awk '{print $5}' | grep [0-9]
```

Based on my understanding, the ls -l prints the lists of directories and files with long format (including the permissions) within the current directory, so piping the awk (to print desired field from the list, which is the size of file) and grep [0-9] gave me the correct output that I want, which is the file size highlighted in red.

For example:
drwxr-xr-x  2 zdgx6 students  103 Feb 23  2017 delosreyes_hw1

Output is 103 (since that's the size and the font is red)

However, when I tried this on my Bash script
like this: `echo " $file size: $( ls -l "$file" | awk '{print $5}' | grep [0-9] ) $regfile "`

it outputs the file size correctly but it's not highlighted in red. So I assume that my syntax may have been wrong but i didn't get any errors.

Any idea why that might be?

Comment: See: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/74329)

Comment: Use [stat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat)

Comment: du -skh <filename>    Try this

Comment: Also its not an error, its red as it matched the pattern you provided, to remove the color, you may use grep [0-9] --color=never

hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Gnu `grep` will highlight the matched part of each line if:

- you supply the command-line argument `--color=always` [Note 1], or
- `stdout` is a terminal and you either supply the command-line argument `--color=auto` or do not specify `--color` (because `auto` is the default setting).

Running `grep` inside `$(...)` in order to capture the output as part of a bash expansion means that `stdout` will be redirected to a pipe, which is not a terminal. So unless you specify `--color=always`, match coloring will be disabled. That's usually want you want when you are processing the output of `grep`.

So you could "fix" this by using the `--color=always` option, but really the simpler solution is to send colour control codes directly, since that is the *only* reason you are using `grep`.

Colour codes can be sent in a reasonably portable way using the `tput` utility, which is part of the `ncurses` package and will generally be installed on any Linux/BSD system. You'll want the following codes:

```
tput bold    # Sets boldface (Otherwise, the colour will be washed out)
tput setaf 1 # 1 is red. 2 is green, 3 yellow, 4 blue, 5 magenta, 6 cyan and 7 white
```

After you output the highlighted text, you'll need to reset the console to normal:

```
tput sgr0    # Normal colour and style
```

So you could do, for example:

```
echo "$file size: $(tput bold)$(tput setaf 1)$(ls -l "$file" | awk '{print $5}')$(tput sgr0) $regfile"
```

If you were doing that a lot, you might want to save the `tput` outputs in bash variables:

```
bold_red=$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 1)
reset_col=$(tput sgr0)

echo "$file size: $(tput bold)$(tput setaf 1)$(ls -l "$file" | awk '{print $5}')$(tput sgr0) $regfile"
```

You could also hard-code typical console codes if you know what they are:

```
printf "%s size: \033[1;31m%s\033m %s\n" "$file" "$(ls -l "$file" | awk '{print $5}')" "$regfile"
```

---

#### Notes

1. For the benefit of those of us with a different notion of English orthography, `grep` allows both `--color` and `--colour`. To avoid confusion, I used the first one in the text here, although I typically use the second out of habit.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "$(tput setaf 1)$(stat -c '%B' file.log)$(tput sgr0)"
512
```

You should not use `ls` to parse the details of any file, you can use `stat` instead. You can issue `stat --help` to check the details of various flags provided by `stat` command. Also by doing this, you do not have to use any additional `pipe` to feed into `awk`.

Comment: This is a good approach, but I'm not sure I understand the advantage of using process substitution into echo instead of just doing `tput setaf 1; stat -c '%B' file.log; tput sgr0`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all! I find that using the grep --color=always was the simplest solution for my question. The other suggestions worked as well but we haven't discussed those commands in class.
Here's my code:

```
 echo " $file $( ls -l "$file" | awk '{print $5}' | grep --color=always [0-9] ) $regfile "
```